# CAShapeLayer - Circle within UIVIew

Tags: swift, uiview, geometry, cashapelayer

I am struggling to draw a circle within a UIView added onto my main view, using Swift 2.0 in Xcode 7.

The UIView has been created in storyboard and declared as an IBOutlet in code:

```
@IBOutlet var circleView: UIView!
```

I have used code from a tutorial online to draw a circle in time to a countdown timer:

```
func createCircle(){

    let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: circleView.frame.width / 2, height: circleView.frame.width / 2)

    // Create CAShapeLayer
    let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
    rectShape.bounds = bounds
    rectShape.position = circleView.center
    rectShape.cornerRadius = bounds.width / 2
    view.layer.addSublayer(rectShape)

    rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rectShape.bounds).CGPath
    rectShape.lineWidth = (bounds.width) / 10 // chnage this to change line width
    rectShape.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    rectShape.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

    rectShape.strokeStart = 0
    rectShape.strokeEnd = 0

    let start = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
    start.toValue = 0
    let end = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    end.toValue = 1

    let group = CAAnimationGroup()
    group.animations = [start, end]
    group.duration = timerDuration
    group.autoreverses = false // use true to bounce it back
    group.repeatCount = 1 // can use the keyword HUGE to repeat forver
    rectShape.addAnimation(group, forKey: nil)

}
```

I have been playing around with the position, but it never seems to center the circle in the center of `circleView`.

Comment: You might be adding it as a sublayer to the wrong view. Try `circleView.layer.addSublayer(rectShape)`

Comment: This line is very unlikely to be right: `rectShape.position = circleView.center`

Answer (score 0):

Here is code I use to make a user's profile image round:

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width / 2


imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

In your case, you would use `circleView` instead of `imageView`.